# Plotly Bar Chart - using a dropdown to select a column, then have the bar chart sort by the column?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, visualization, plotly-python

#### What I'm trying to achieve:

I'd like to have a single horizontal bar chart in plotly python with a single dropdown menu. The dropdown menu options are all column names for a given dataframe. I want the bar chart to sort itself according to whatever column is selected in the dropdown. Is such a thing possible?

#### What I currently have:

I have a dataframe that looks like this:
[image]

And my code for the plot looks like this:

```py
def gen_bar(df, title, sub, col='Podium'):
    """
    Displays an interactive plotly graph using the given column and dataframe.
    
    df: dataframe containing relevant data
    col: data to be displayed along x-axis
    title: title (and subtitle) for given visualization
    """
    # Top 10 men and women
    comb = df.sort_values(col, ascending=False)[:20]
    
    # Define colors
    color_discrete_map = {"M": "#10baee", "F": "#ff007e"}
    
    # Define plot
    fig=go.Figure()
    for r in comb['Name'].unique():
        dfp = comb[comb['Name'] == r]
        g = dfp['Gender'].values[0]
        fig.add_traces(
            go.Bar(x=dfp[col], 
                   y=dfp['Name'],
                   customdata=[col],
                   name='', 
                   marker_color=color_discrete_map[g], 
                   orientation='h',
                   hovertemplate="<b>%{y}</b><br>%{customdata}: %{x}"
                   ))
        
    
# Define buttons for dropdown
    col_opts = list(df.columns[4:])
    buttons_opts = []
    for i, opt in enumerate(col_opts):
        args = [False] * len(col_opts)
        args[i] = True
        buttons_opts.append(
            dict(
                method='restyle',
                label=opt,
                args=[{
                    'visible': args, #this is the key line!
                    'title': opt,
                    'showlegend': False
                }]
            )
        )
        
    # Styling
    title = f"{title}<br><sup>{sub}"
    fig.update_layout(
        updatemenus = [go.layout.Updatemenu(
            active=col_opts.index(col),
            buttons=buttons_opts,
            x=1.12,
            xanchor='right',
            y=1.1,
            yanchor='top'
            )],
        yaxis={
            'autorange': "reversed",
            'showline': True,
            'linecolor': 'black',
            'title': None
        },
        title=dict(text=title, font=dict(size=30)),
        showlegend=False,
        width=1000,
        height=600,
        plot_bgcolor='#f0f0f0',
        paper_bgcolor='#f0f0f0',
        xaxis_title=None,
        margin=dict(l=85, r=85, t=95, b=45)
    )
    
    fig.show(config=config)
    
title = "Top 20 Climbers in IFSC"
sub = f"Based on total number of given value"
gen_bar(all_boulder_podiums, title, sub, 'Podium')
```

#### Which produces this plot:

[image]

#### The problem:

While the dropdown works, the chart doesn't update correctly. I don't know enough about plotly to really figure out where I'm going wrong, but for example if I pick the 'Gold' column from the dropdown, the cart updates to this:

[image]

How can I implement the desired changes? I figured it wouldn't be too difficult, but here I am, several hours later trying to figure this out. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the cause is that individual graphs are created by name. So the graphs are created with data frames sorted in descending order of the target column, and set to display only the first one. Also, for gender color coding, I need a list of colors, so I create a list of colors by referring to a dictionary from the data frame. The Active button determines the number of the graph to be displayed as the initial display, and is set to the first graph you want to show (default value is 0).

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def gen_bar(df, title, sub):
    """
    Displays an interactive plotly graph using the given column and dataframe.
    
    df: dataframe containing relevant data
    col: data to be displayed along x-axis
    title: title (and subtitle) for given visualization
    """
    # Top 10 men and women
    #comb = df.sort_values(col, ascending=False)[:20]
    comb = df[:20]
    
    # Define colors
    color_discrete_map = {"M": "#10baee", "F": "#ff007e"}
    
    # Define plot
    fig=go.Figure()
    for k,r in enumerate(df.columns[4:]):
        #dfp = comb[comb['Name'] == r]
        dfp = comb.sort_values(r, ascending=False)
        g = dfp['Gender'].values
        print(g)
        colors = [color_discrete_map[x] for x in g]
        fig.add_traces(
            go.Bar(x=dfp[r], 
                   y=dfp['Name'],
                   customdata=dfp[r].values,
                   name='', 
                   marker_color=colors,#color_discrete_map[g], 
                   orientation='h',
                   hovertemplate="<b>%{y}</b><br>%{customdata}: %{x}",
                   visible=True if k == 0 else False
                   ))
        
    
# Define buttons for dropdown
    col_opts = list(df.columns[4:])
    buttons_opts = []
    for i, opt in enumerate(col_opts):
        args = [False] * len(col_opts)
        args[i] = True
        buttons_opts.append(
            dict(
                method='restyle',
                label=opt,
                args=[{
                    'visible': args, #this is the key line!
                    'title': opt,
                    'showlegend': False
                }]
            )
        )
        
    # Styling
    title = f"{title}<br><sup>{sub}"
    fig.update_layout(
        updatemenus = [go.layout.Updatemenu(
            active=0,#col_opts.index(col),
            buttons=buttons_opts,
            x=1.12,
            xanchor='right',
            y=1.1,
            yanchor='top'
            )],
        yaxis={
            'autorange': "reversed",
            'showline': True,
            'linecolor': 'black',
            'title': None
        },
        title=dict(text=title, font=dict(size=30)),
        showlegend=False,
        width=1000,
        height=600,
        plot_bgcolor='#f0f0f0',
        paper_bgcolor='#f0f0f0',
        xaxis_title=None,
        margin=dict(l=85, r=85, t=95, b=45)
    )
    # print(fig.data)
    fig.show()#config=config
    
title = "Top 20 Climbers in IFSC"
sub = f"Based on total number of given value"
gen_bar(all_boulder_podiums, title, sub)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This was very helpful! I did eventually figure it out on my own, but I think your answer is definitely cleaner and easier to understand than mine! I appreciate it. :)